# SwiftUI Make the content of an Image reactive to a property update

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have this inside my View:

```
Image(uiImage: viewModel.emojiImage)

Button(action: {
    viewModel.updatesRandomEmojiImage()
}, label: {
    Text("RANDOM EMOJI")
}).buttonStyle(FilledButton())
```

and these methods in my ViewModel:

```
@State var emojiImage: UIImage = UIImage()

func updatesRandomEmojiImage() {
    guard let url = URL(string: randomEmojiUrl()) else { return }
    downloadEmojiImage(fromUrl: url)
}
    
func randomEmojiUrl() -> String {
    repository.emojis().randomElement()?.imageUrl ?? ""
}
    
private func downloadEmojiImage(fromUrl url: URL) {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        self.emojiImage = UIImage(data: data)!
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make that the `Image` content changes whenever I click on the "RANDOM EMOJI" button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for this problem. What I did was:

In VM I made my image a @Published instead of @State:

```
@Published var emojiImage: UIImage? = nil
```

Then, in the View what I did was add the `.onReceive` call and an image using @State:

```
@State private var emojiImage: UIImage?

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        emojiImage.map{Image(uiImage: $0)}             
    }.onReceive(viewModel.$emojiImage) { image 
        self.emojiImage = image
    }
}
```